# Total Variation Metric for Probability Measure: Set of Variation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

As I understand it, the total variation distance gives the maximum difference between two probability measures. Is there any formalization of something like a set of variation, the "smallest" set that "achieves" the total variation?